# Split one table to multiple tables

Tags: r, split, datatables, dplyr

Actually I have a big table that I want to split to multiple tables based on specific column's values.
For that I use the subset function like this :

```r
lapply(1:18, function(i) subset(table,bucket==i))
```

The problem is that I don't know how to assign each mini-table to its name like table_1 for i=1, table_2 for i=2 ...

Comment: Take a look at [`split`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html). If you provide a sample of your `table` would be easier to help you out.

Comment: To add to @patL 's comment, try `split(table, table$bucket)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it works :

```r
for (i in unique(table$bucket))
{
  assign(  paste("table_", i, sep = ""), subset(table,bucket==i) )
}
```

Do you know if there is a way to avoid using the For loop?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)

sampler1 <- data.frame(LobsterID=c("Lobster1","Lobster1","Lobster2",
                                   "Lobster2","Lobster2","Lobster2",
                                   "Lobster2","Lobster3","Lobster3","Lobster3"),
                       Area=c(.4,.35,1.1,1.04,1.14,1.1,1.05,1.7,1.63,1.8),
                       Sampler=c(rep("Sampler1", 10)))
sampler2 <- data.frame(LobsterID=c("Lobster1","Lobster1","Lobster1",
                                   "Lobster1","Lobster1","Lobster2",
                                   "Lobster2","Lobster2","Lobster4","Lobster4"),
                       Area=c(.41,.44,.47,.43,.38,1.14,1.11,1.09,1.41,1.4),
                       Sampler=c(rep("Sampler2", 10)))

combined <- bind_rows(sampler1, sampler2)

combined

splitout <- split(combined, combined$LobsterID)
splitout
```

Results:

```
$Lobster1
   LobsterID Area  Sampler
1   Lobster1 0.40 Sampler1
2   Lobster1 0.35 Sampler1
11  Lobster1 0.41 Sampler2
12  Lobster1 0.44 Sampler2
13  Lobster1 0.47 Sampler2
14  Lobster1 0.43 Sampler2
15  Lobster1 0.38 Sampler2

$Lobster2
   LobsterID Area  Sampler
3   Lobster2 1.10 Sampler1
4   Lobster2 1.04 Sampler1
5   Lobster2 1.14 Sampler1
6   Lobster2 1.10 Sampler1
7   Lobster2 1.05 Sampler1
16  Lobster2 1.14 Sampler2
17  Lobster2 1.11 Sampler2
18  Lobster2 1.09 Sampler2

$Lobster3
   LobsterID Area  Sampler
8   Lobster3 1.70 Sampler1
9   Lobster3 1.63 Sampler1
10  Lobster3 1.80 Sampler1

$Lobster4
   LobsterID Area  Sampler
19  Lobster4 1.41 Sampler2
20  Lobster4 1.40 Sampler2
```